# gem5 simulation time is high

Tags: time, simulation, gem5

good day every body 
I have a real problem here that took a near of couple weeks on searching but without a conclusion 
I'm trying to run a compiled c++ code (a binary file) on gem5 to measure the time consumed for some architectures I made using python and make my compare to show the statistics etc.. 
this would look OK using binaries that take a small amount of time to finish but when a binary should take let's say 2 seconds for example, the simulation time would be really big
how to resolve this issue, I need simulation time optimized as possible
I think it would be easy but I'm not able to figure it out until now :\ 
what I reached until now is: 
- building gem5 in fast mode, but that did not give me any difference from the optimized mode in the simulation time
- using the fast forwarding in the optimized mode, however. I could not get that done until now
any help please !

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

- You can use  Classical Memory model if the program does not involve complex memory interactions. This would be faster than the Ruby model.
- Fast forward your application upto the point where the real computation begins. You mentioned it did not work for you. One thing to check would be : if you're using Ruby memory model, that doesn't support fast forwarding. It works with Classic memory model. http://www.m5sim.org/General_Memory_System
- Another thing that might be of interest to you is Simpoints, which can characterize the important sections of your app so that you run those instead of the complete app. Of course, you might want to run the complete app later, but this can give you a decent first order comparison across architectures. Check http://gem5.org/Simpoints

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things that I did to overcome the ridiculously long running times of gem5

1. **Upgrade your hardware**. Upgrading my hard drive to a solid-state drive did it for me a few years ago. Android Gingerbread used to take 3 hours to boot for me, but after the upgrade it took 1 hour.
2. **Use Atomic CPU**. If you don't need to study the memory system, then just use the atomic CPU model without caches
3. **Set it and forget it**. If you have access to a server, then put some jobs to run, get some coffee, take a nap, play some soccer, work on something else, and then come back and check on your jobs